# Padding does not work with div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am not a front-end developer so I suspect I might be missing something really basic. Nevertheless I cannot figure out a solution.
I have a `div` element and I simply want to apply some `padding` at the top so that it does't interfere with the heading. I have looked around and I have seen similar problems with margin collapsing but I don't think it's the case since here I am dealing with two separate `div` not enclosing each other (`tot-header` and `content`).This is what I have written so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blogologo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="css/head.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="tot-header">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Blogologo</h1>
            </div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Racconti</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Rubriche</a></li> 
                      <li><a href="#">Pesce fritto e baccal&#224;</a></li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">                          
                    <div id="central" class="col-md-8">
                        Preview
                    </div>
                    <div id="side" class="col-md-4">
                        <ul class="side-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Racconti</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Rubriche</a></li> 
                          <li><a href="#">Pesce fritto e baccal&#224;</a></li> 
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the css

```
.tot-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.content {
    padding-top: 10cm;
}
```

However the padding seems not to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using? From what I can see it seems to be working perfectly. There is a huge space between the two divs caused by the `padding-top` of the `.content` div. That is until your scroll, because your top header has a fixed position.

This is your code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WweMPG?editors=1100

```css
.tot-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 10cm;
}
```

```html
<div class="tot-header">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Blogologo</h1>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Racconti</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Rubriche</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pesce fritto e baccal&#224;</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="central" class="col-md-8">
        Preview
      </div>
      <div id="side" class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="side-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Racconti</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Rubriche</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pesce fritto e baccal&#224;</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code appears to me to be working perfectly. What did you expect it to look like?

Answer (score 1):

remove

`position:fixed;`

and change your  .content css

from `padding-top:10cm;`  to  `padding-top:10px;`

Answer (score 0):

in your css you can try using pixels instead of cm e.g.

```
.content {
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Also you may try using margin instead of padding e.g.

```
.content {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

And give it more padding or margin untill your content appears